# Vagrant not working properly

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra, vagrant

I have a vagrant file that uses chef to help install things:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'opscode-ubuntu-12.04_chef-11.4.0'
  config.vm.box_url = 'https://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/opscode_ubuntu-12.04_chef-11.4.0.box'
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

  config.vm.provider(:virtualbox) do |vb|
    vb.customize [
      "modifyvm", :id,
      "--memory", "1024",
      "--cpus",   "4"
    ]
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: %Q{
    sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-client
  }

  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = ["cookbooks"]
    chef.add_recipe :apt
    chef.add_recipe 'postgresql::server'
    chef.add_recipe 'build-essential'
    chef.add_recipe 'rvm::vagrant'
    chef.add_recipe 'rvm::system'
    chef.add_recipe 'git'
    chef.json = {
      :postgresql => {
    :version => '9.3'
      },
      "postgresql" => {
        "password" => {
          "postgres" => "kshgfi3ret3hihjfbkivtbo3ity835"
        }
      },
      "database" => {
        "create" => ["aisisplatform"]
      },
      :git   => {
        :prefix => "/usr/local"
      },
      :rvm => {
        'rubies' => [ 'ruby-2.1.0' ],
        'default_ruby' => 'ruby-2.1.0',
        'vagrant' => {
          :system_chef_solo => '/usr/bin/chef-solo'
        }
      },
    }
  end
end
```

There are a few issues with this:

- Through out the `vagrant up` start up I get warnings like this:

  `/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/rvm_chef_user_environment.rb:32: warning: class variable access from toplevel`
- The next issue is that things don't work properly, some times the vm sees PostgreSQL, through the `psql` command, sometimes it doesn't know what it is and states it's not installed. when it does see it, it states that `psql: FATAL:  role "vagrant" does not exist`
- The final issue is that when the vm boots up there is well over 200 updates of both regular and security. I would like this to be taken care of when the vm is set up the first time, via `vagrant up`. I tried doing:

  config.vm.provision :shell, inline: %Q{
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade -y
  }

But when the script runs I get **TON** of errors about `stdn` and so on and so forth. So, what do I do to fix these? what's wrong with my vagrant file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I adapted the vagrant file to use the omnibus and berkshelf plugins. The former will ensure chef is at the desired version and the latter keeps the cookbooks up-to-date.

I also noted the "class variable access" warnings, whose root cause is presumably buried in the rvm cookbook. I didn't look deeper because my Vagrant run completed without error.

## Example

```
$ tree
.
├── Berksfile
└── Vagrantfile
```

### Berksfile

```
site :opscode

cookbook "apt"
cookbook "postgresql"
cookbook "build-essential"
cookbook "rvm", :github => "fnichol/chef-rvm"
cookbook "git"
```

### Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-omnibus"
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-berkshelf"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  # Box config
  config.vm.box = 'precise64'
  config.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box'

  # Plugin config
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  # Network config
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

  # Virtual config
  config.vm.provider(:virtualbox) do |vb|
    vb.customize [
      "modifyvm", :id,
      "--memory", "1024",
      "--cpus",   "4"
    ]
  end

  # Provisioner config
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe 'apt'
    chef.add_recipe 'postgresql::client'
    chef.add_recipe 'postgresql::server'
    chef.add_recipe 'build-essential'
    chef.add_recipe 'rvm::system'
    chef.add_recipe 'git'
    chef.json = {
      :postgresql => {
        :version => '9.3'
      },
      "postgresql" => {
        "password" => {
          "postgres" => "kshgfi3ret3hihjfbkivtbo3ity835"
        }
      },
      "database" => {
        "create" => ["aisisplatform"]
      },
      :git   => {
        :prefix => "/usr/local"
      },
      :rvm => {
        'rubies' => [ 'ruby-2.1.0' ],
        'default_ruby' => 'ruby-2.1.0',
        'vagrant' => {
          :system_chef_solo => '/usr/bin/chef-solo'
        }
      },
    }
  end
end
```

Notes:

- A standard Ubuntu image can be used. The omnibus plugin will install Chef 11.10 automatically
- The "rvm::vagrant" recipe was removed as unncessary. Chef is installed using the omnibus installer and will therefore have it's own embedded ruby version
- Used the "postgresql::client" recipe instead of a shell provisioner.

Comment: Your's gave me errors: `stdin: is not a tty` and `/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/rvm/libraries/rvm_chef_user_environment.rb:49: warning: class variable access from top-level` which repeated it's self 3 more times. Not to meant ion doing `vagrant ssh` after followed by a `psql` gives me: `psql: FATAL:  role "vagrant" does not exist` I thought this was all take care of for me?

Comment: The "tty" and "class variable" messages are warnings, not errors. Chef completes doesn't it? As for your psql error this is a separate issue which *you* have asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801837/psql-fatal-role-vagrant-does-not-exist