# psql: FATAL: role "vagrant" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, psql

I created a vagrant instance and I am getting this error every time I try and do `psql` in the terminal How would Fix it. the error is as states:

psql: FATAL:  role "vagrant" does not exist

I thought vagrant takes care of this? This is my vagrant file:

```
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-omnibus"
Vagrant.require_plugin "vagrant-berkshelf"

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  # Box config
  config.vm.box = 'precise64'
  config.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box'

  # Plugin config
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  # Network config
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000

  # Virtual config
  config.vm.provider(:virtualbox) do |vb|
    vb.customize [
      "modifyvm", :id,
      "--memory", "1024",
      "--cpus",   "4"
    ]
  end

  # Provisioner config
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.add_recipe 'apt'
    chef.add_recipe 'postgresql::client'
    chef.add_recipe 'postgresql::server'
    chef.add_recipe 'build-essential'
    chef.add_recipe 'rvm::system'
    chef.add_recipe 'git'
    chef.json = {
      :postgresql => {
        :version => '9.3'
      },
      "postgresql" => {
        "password" => {
          "postgres" => "kshgfi3ret3hihjfbkivtbo3ity835"
        }
      },
      "database" => {
        "create" => ["aisisplatform"]
      },
      :git   => {
        :prefix => "/usr/local"
      },
      :rvm => {
        'rubies' => [ 'ruby-2.1.0' ],
        'default_ruby' => 'ruby-2.1.0',
        'vagrant' => {
          :system_chef_solo => '/usr/bin/chef-solo'
        }
      },
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have `vagrant` user in postgres, and when you run `psql`, it tries to login as `vagrant` user (the same name as OS user). You may try something like:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

to login as `postgres` user, with password specified in your Vagrantfile for `postgresq` user.

Then, you have several options:

- Export `PGUSER` and `PGHOST` [environment variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-envars.html) to set user and host (`psql` without parameters will use these values). You may also want to use [.pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) file to avoid entering password on each `psql` execute.
- Modify Vagrantfile to create `vagrant` user in postgres with password

Comment: What would creating a vagrant user in the the Vagrantfile look like? I've tried entering `"password" => {"vagrant" => "kshgfi3ret3hihjfbkivtbo3ity835"}`, but it complains about no "postgres" attribute.

Comment: Mine looks like this 
`postgresql: {
           version: "9.3",
           password: {postgres: "some_pass"},
           database_name: "mobi_test"
           },`

Comment: psql -U user1 -h localhost -d database1